# Searching for blob field in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have column in my database that stores BLOB.
I want to run a query to check if specific byte array value is present in the table.
The value is `b'\xf4\x8f\xc6{\xc2mH(\x97\x9c\x83hkE\x8b\x95'` (python bytes).

I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT * from received_message 
WHERE "EphemeralID" 
LIKE HEX('\xf4\x8f\xc6{\xc2mH(\x97\x9c\x83hkE\x8b\x95');
```

But I get 0 results though I 100% sure that I store this value in the database.

Is there something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Your search string is a bit weird-- you appear to have some complex things in there like { and (.  Maybe you should search through the blob the way it is stored instead?

From the Sqlite documentation:

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and
>   preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

So maybe do a like with the ascii representation of the hex value you want?  Maybe start with looking for just f48f or F48F if your sqlite stores it upper case.